# How can I distinguish P and N channel MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

I have ordered MOSFETs. Both N and both P channel ones:

- N-channel MOSFET - 5LN01SP
- P-Channel MOSFET - 5LP01SP

But it came without labelled container, and writing on them are as follows:

- YB 7C
- XB 4M

I could not find anything by these search terms.

How can I distinguish which of these are P and which are N channel MOSFETs? (with a multimeter, and some basic discrete components: resistors, capacitors, batteries, etc)

(Of course without destroying anything :) )

Comment: Add the part numbers of the MOSFETs you've ordered. Often you'll find markings indication within the datasheet.

Comment: Look at the datasheets; the package markings should be there.

Comment: (A "transistor tester" kit with a ZIF socket and test leads is a useful piece of test equipment for $20 or less; they act as LCR meters too. You can even get the kit with a case if you want.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming these are the standard 3-pin MOSFETs (and not a four-pin FET with separate substrate connection):

- Use a multimeter in diode test mode to identify the two pins that appear to have a diode between them. This is the body diode. Take note of which way the diode was forward-biased.
- Construct an amplifier, with the unknown transistor placed according to the orientation of the body diode and no other info:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffR1HW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If M1 is an nFET, this is a common-source amplifier. Connecting the gate to 0 V will cause the output to rise to 5 V, and connecting the gate to 5 V will cause the output to drop to essentially 0 V.

If M1 is a pFET, it's a common-drain buffer. Connecting the gate to 0 V will cause the output to rise to approximately Vth, and connecting the gate to 5 V will cause the output to rise to 5 V.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is in the [data sheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/4/2/3/5ln01sp.PDF): -

[image]

And, if you read the data sheet for the other device it lists XB as the marking.

Answer (score 4):

If you check the datasheets for the parts you will see that:

[5LN01SP datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/EN6559_D-310419.pdf) shows the marking is "YB" on page 1.

[5LP01SP datasheet](https://www.mouser.be/datasheet/2/308/1/EN6621_D-348057.pdf) shows marking "XB".

Answer (score 1):

Given you know what MOSFETs you ordered and have their datasheets, what prevents you from actually building a switch circuit and seeing what is what?

if you don't have a datasheet, as a rule of thumb, maximum Vgs after which they break down is often 12V, sometimes 8V. So make a 6V-7V led circuit (1mA, small LEDs) and try to switch it with a low-side MOSFET. If it behaves like expected, it's N. If not, it's P.